# Knockout JS show hide div based on page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to split two different section based on page URL. I'm not aware how to do it using knockout.

The below example I have tried so far.

```
<!-- ko if: attr: { href: https://stackoverflow.com } -->
    <p>Div 1</p>
 <!-- /ko -->
 
  <!-- ko if: attr: { href: https://getbootstrap.com } -->
    <p>Div 2</p>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Any clarification please drop a comment. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template system to perform this kind of switch :

```js
ko.applyBindings({
    stackoverflowData : {
    totalQuestions : 321
  },  
  bootstrapData : {
    version : '5.0.2'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'stackoverflow-template', data: stackoverflowData }"></div>
<hr />
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'bootstrapData-template', data: bootstrapData }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="stackoverflow-template">
  stackoverflow specific view <br />
  Questions: <span data-bind="text: totalQuestions"></span>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="bootstrapData-template">
  bootstrapData specific view <br />
  Version <span data-bind="text: version"></span>
</script>
```

If you want something dynamic you can create a function that returns the template to use based on the viewmodel.

```js
function getTemplate(url) {
  // use reg ex
  if (url == 'https://stackoverflow.com')
    return 'stackoverflow';
  if (url == 'https://getbootstrap.com')
    return 'bootstrap';
  return null;
}


var websites = [{
    url: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    specificData: {
      totalQuestions: 321
    }
  },
  {
    url: 'https://getbootstrap.com',
    specificData: {
      version: '5.0.2'
    }
  }
];


websites.map(function(website) {
  website.template = ko.computed(function() {
    return getTemplate(this.url);
  }, website);
  return website;
})

ko.applyBindings({
  websites: websites
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: websites">
  <div data-bind="template: { name: (template()+'-template'), data: specificData }">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="stackoverflow-template">
  stackoverflow specific view <br /> Questions: <span data-bind="text: totalQuestions"></span>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="bootstrap-template">
  bootstrapData specific view <br /> Version <span data-bind="text: version"></span>
</script>
```

Comment: I want to show either one at a time based on URL. I think this solution will not help me to resolve the issue. Also I want to bind the URL not this `321`

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you'll need to bring the url into your viewmodel. You could do this with a simple custom `url` bindinghandler. When initialized, it stores the current url in the bound observable (in this case `myUrl`) and adds an event listener for storing a changed url (in this case I use hash change to be able to make the example work).

Now, in HTML you can show or hide divs based on this observable value. Have a look at the example below.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.url = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    valueAccessor()(location.href);

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(ev) {
      valueAccessor()(ev.newURL);
    });
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  myUrl: ko.observable(),
  showDiv1: function() {
    window.location.hash = 'div1'
  },
  showDiv2: function() {
    window.location.hash = 'div2'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>
  Current url: <em data-bind="text: myUrl"></em>
</p>
<button data-bind="click: showDiv1">Show Div 1</button>
<button data-bind="click: showDiv2">Show Div 2</button>

<div data-bind="url: myUrl">
  <!-- ko if: myUrl() == "https://stacksnippets.net/js#div1" -->
  <p>Div 1</p>
  <p data-bind="text: myUrl"></p>
  <!-- /ko -->

  <!-- ko if: myUrl() == "https://stacksnippets.net/js#div2" -->
  <p>Div 2</p>
  <p data-bind="text: myUrl"></p>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Without click show div how can I load URL automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by loading the URL automatically? The buttons are only there for demonstrating what happens when the URL changes.